# How to load an Object from its stack and removing it, to show the next one

Tags: swift, swiftui

My app is very similar to Tinder, where users *match* by swiping people's profiles either to the right (like) or to the left (reject).

Only problem I'm facing is identifying each one of the users that are displayed in the `HomeView`, how to remove that user, display the next one, and knowing which liked user has to be taken as parameter in the network calls.

**The `Person` struct:**

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var age: Int
    var username: String
}
```

**The `CardView` in which every `Person` is displayed:**

```
struct CardView: View {
    @State var person: Person

    var body: some View {
                ZStack {
                     Image()
                       .frame(width: 200, height: 600)
                VStack() {
                    HStack {
                        Text(person.username)
                             .font(.system(size: 32, weight: .heavy))
                                
                        Text(String(person.age))
                             .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .light))
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**And `CardStack`, where a `ForEach` gets every `Person` in userMng.people:**

```
struct CardStack: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var userMng: UserManager
    var person: Person

    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(userMng.people, id: \.self) { user in
                    CardView(person: person)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: screen.width, height: fullscreenMode ? screen.height : 550)
    }
}
```

```
class UserManager: ObservableObject {

   @Published var people: [Person] = []

   public func swipe(_ person: Person, _direction: SwipeDirection) { // Networking to backend
           
        switch _direction {
        case .like:
            sendFriendRequest(to: person.uid)
        case .nope:
            print("nope")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Finally, the `HomeView` where the user decides which person does they like or not:**

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userMng: UserManager
    @State var person: Person?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
               CardStack(person: person ?? Person(data: ["username": "ExampleUsername"]))
        
        HStack { // Here is where all three buttons are shown

            CircleButtonView(type: .no) {
                // Button action...
            }

            CircleButtonView(type: .back) {
                // Button action...
            }

            CircleButtonView(type: .heart) {
                 if let person = userMng.people.last {
                     userMng.swipe(person, _direction: .like)
                 }
            }
        }
        }
    } 
}
```

Only thing that comes to my mind is using a `currentIndex` for each user displayed, but have no idea how to implement it, if being honest.

Comment: Have a look at this video, its very short and perfect explanation what do you want to achive. [Tinder Like Swipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIW9HWGnbnw)

Comment: That video in specific doesn't solve my problem but the channel has an interesting Tinder clone project in a list I didn't know about, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think having zstack on all available people is a good idea, as that will take a lot of memory.  Loading each person's carview at the user's swipe should do the job with a lot less resouce.

But if you want to keep the zstack, you just need to add removeLast() at swipe, as only last object will be removed and then the view will update itself.

```
class UserManager: ObservableObject {

   @Published var people: [Person] = []

   public func swipe(_ person: Person, _direction: SwipeDirection) { // Networking to backend
        people.removeLast()
        switch _direction {
        case .like:
            sendFriendRequest(to: person.uid)
        case .nope:
            print("nope")
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Exactly right, a ZStack was an awful idea but i just wanted to see if everyone got loaded. Would this change if I would load each one of them once swiped?

Comment: probably not, view-related and networkingcodes should be added, but managing people array should be the same